# Симуляция медленной скорости загрузки (upload) на сервер

Tags: google-chrome, apache, php, тестирование, ubuntu

Возникла задача потестить процесс загрузки файлов на сервер. Но на локальном сервере они загружаются за доли секунды, поэтому вопрос - как симулировать медленный коннект? Желательно малой кровью, по минимуму утилит и настроек. Система ubuntu 12.04, сервер apache2, браузер Chrome.

Comment: [http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/861/how-can-i-simulate-a-slow-connection-for-page-load][1]

[1]: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/861/how-can-i-simulate-a-slow-connection-for-page-load

Comment: не подходит, firefox throttle несовместим с последним firefox, а остальные предложенные решения - для удаленных серверов

Comment: @gridsane Пишут, что `Fiddler` работает и для `localhost`. Это же просто проксик с настраиваемым `bandwidth`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx + [upload module](http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.ru.html)

Пример конфигурации есть по ссылке выше. Скорость закачки регулируется при помощи директивы `upload_limit_rate`.

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня не nginx. Есть подобный модуль для apache?

Comment: Есть ли модуль для апатча - не знаю. Но nginx можно поставить поверх апатча.

Кстати, если вы загружаете большие файлы, то я в любом случае рекомендовал бы использовать этот (или аналогичный модуль для апатча, если такой есть). Поскольку прогоняя загружаемый файл через fastcgi вы получаете достаточно большой overhead.

Comment: Спасибо за совет)

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая программка как Fiddler. Она умеет имитировать модемную скорость, а сама по себе очень маленькая и простая.